# Is there any way to block a specify file type (mime type) from Azure App Services in the Azure Portal?

Tags: mime-types, azure-appservice, azure-webapps

There is a specific file type (.inc) I would like to block so it cannot be served from any of my web sites. The sites are Azure app services and are managed through the Azure Portal. I have searched for a way to disable / enable various mime types but cannot find anyplace to do it in the portal. This was possible with older versions of IIS. Is there any way it can be done in the Portal, or (less preferable) via web.config?

Comment: In azure portal open `web app` -> `configurations` -> `path mapping` -> select `New handler mapping` as shown in [image](https://i.imgur.com/HrItyYt.png) -> enter the extension that you need to block as shown in [image](https://i.imgur.com/20OGUyn.png)

Comment: In azure portal open web app -> configurations -> path mapping -> select New application settings name as `WEBSITE_BLOCK_MIME_TYPE` and value: `fileExtension.inc` as shown in the [image](https://i.imgur.com/PlnZfwn.png)